# Git: How to reuse commit rev across commit --amend?

Tags: git

My release file's name depends on `commit=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)`, and I want to put the release file to my git repo. When do some amend commit, the `$commit` changed, is it possible to reuse the `$commit` after `git commit --amend`?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like answers this simple: No.

Comment: @jthill: Is it impossible to reuse?

Comment: It's how commit id's are generated: different content has different id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Here are some of the things that goes into the sha-1, the value returned by `git rev-parse --short` and that will cause the sha-1 to change:

- Name of author
- Date of commit
- Commit message
- List of parents

and, most important

- **the sha-1 of all the files and directories in the repository**. Adding even a space character to one of the files will make it impossible to get the same sha-1 again.

Answer (score 0):

`git commit --amend --no-edit`

this keep the commit message (if this is what you want)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

This is because of how Git works at a fundamental level. Every commit in Git, and just about everything *else* in Git, is a binary object called a *blob*.

Some blobs are particular revisions of the files you're storing; these blobs are independent of all the other blobs. Some blobs, though, refer to other blobs. The key used to refer to another blob is the sha-1 hash of the blob itself. A commit object refers, recursively, to its parent commits (by their hashes) and to all of the objects comprising the state of the repository for *that* commit. The commit blob also contains the metadata, including the timestamp *and the commit message*.

So when you change the commit message for a commit, you are changing the contents of the blob, so the sha-1 is different. Like any hashing algorithm, sha-1 output is *very* different even for small changes (this is a large part of the point of a hashing algorithm).

There is no way to avoid this. Blobs are referenced by the sha-1 of their contents; a commit message is a blob; the commit-blob must somehow contain the commit information, including the commit message.